# PowerShell's replace operator fails to find this RegEx pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

For example if I have a text called `$MarkdownText` whose content is this :

---

This is not in a code block

```
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
```

This is not in a code block

```
Command 4
Command 5
Command 6
```

---

I am trying to parse any strings in the text that are wrapped in pairs of three backticks, like so:

```
This is not in a code block

[code]
Command 1
Command 2
Command 3
[/code]

This is not in a code block
[code]
Command 4
Command 5
Command 6
[/code]
```

My code in PowerShell so far is:

````
$MarkdownText = Get-Content -Path "./codebloack.md" -Raw

$MarkdownText -Replace '```\n(.*?)\n```', '[code]$1[/code]' | Set-Content -Path .\Output.txt
````

When I run both lines, I don't get any errors at all Powershell creates the `Output.txt` file but nothing is changed, Its exactly the same as the input file.

My RegEx matches just fine on RegE101, [HERE](https://regex101.com/r/tj5QQe/1) is the link.

I am sooo close to completing this project, just stuck on this last tag

PS: I know there are libraries that will do this sort of thing in a much better way but I am using this to learn PowerShell and Regular Expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use

````
(?s)```\r?\n(.*?)\r?\n```
````

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%60%60%60%5Cr%3F%5Cn%28.*%3F%29%5Cr%3F%5Cn%60%60%60&i=This%20is%20not%20in%20a%20code%20block%0D%0A%0D%0A%60%60%60%0D%0ACommand%201%0D%0ACommand%202%0D%0ACommand%203%0D%0A%60%60%60%0D%0AThis%20is%20not%20in%20a%20code%20block%0D%0A%0D%0A%60%60%60%0D%0ACommand%204%0D%0ACommand%205%0D%0ACommand%206%0D%0A%60%60%60%0D%0AThis%20is%20not%20in%20a%20code%20block%0D%0A%0D%0A). *Details*:

- `(?s)` - a `RegexOptions.Singleline` option
- ```` ``` ```` - three backticks
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line ending
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible
- `\r?\n` - a CRLF or LF line ending
- ```` ``` ```` - three backticks

Answer (score 4):

Wiktor's answer contains the gist of the solution, but let me break it down conceptually:

- The primary problem with your approach is: Since you're trying **to make `.*?` match across *multiple lines***, you need [**inline regex option `(?s)`** (`Singleline`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options), so as **to ensure that `.` also matches *newline* characters (`\n`)**
- Additionally, to get the substitution you want in terms of line formatting, you need to *include* the newlines immediately after the opening and before the closing ```` ``` ````.
- Your solution attempt assumes Unix-format LF-only newlines (`\n`) in the input file. If there's a chance that you may also encounter Windows-format CLRF (`\r\n`) newlines, use `\r?\n` to match *either* format, as also shown in Wiktor's answer.

Therefore:

````
$MarkdownText -replace '(?s)```(\r?\n.*?\r?\n)```', '[code]$1[/code]'
````

---

As for **what you tried**:

[Your own regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/tj5QQe/1):

- used the wrong regex "flavor" (PHP),
- and assumed options to be in effect *outside the regex itself*, some of which aren't turned on by default in PowerShell, namely `m` and `s`.

Because you used `s`, the equivalent of .NET's `(?s)` / `SingleLine` option, your regex happened to work on the site, but since that option *isn't* turned on by default in PowerShell code, it failed there.

See next section for how to use regex101.com with PowerShell.

---

##### Using [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) with PowerShell regex operations:

Note:

- While [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) is a similar site that is specific to .NET regexes (which PowerShell builds on), the multi-flavor (multi-dialect) regex101.com is more fully featured, notably with respect to visualizing the matches and its ability to *explain* a given regex.
- The information below assumes that regex101.com offers *no* PowerShell-specific flavor, which is true as of this writing. Currently, the C#-focused .NET flavor must be used, which requires some extra preparatory work. **[GitHub issue #1838](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/1838) asks for a PowerShell flavor to be introduced in the future**.

Use the following **settings for PowerShell regexes**:

- Under **`FLAVOR`** on the panel in the left, choose **`.NET (C#)`**
- In the **`REGULAR EXPRESSION` input field**:

  - **Set the options**: Click on the active regex options  (`gm` by default) to **select only those options that PowerShell applies *by default***; use **[*inline regex options*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-options) for all *non-default* options, *as part of your regex***; you can use a single `(?...)` specifier for *multiple* options, e.g. `(?sm)` to active both `s` and `m`:

    - In short: for a **`-replace`** operation, ensure that **only options `gi`** are selected (as shown in the screenshot below), for a **`-match` operation**, only use **`i`**; to spell it out:
    - Select `insensitive` (`i`), to match PowerShell's case-insensitive default behavior.

      - If you need case-*sensitive* behavior, use the `c`-prefixed operator variant in PowerShell, e.g. `-creplace` instead of `-replace`
    - *Unselect* `multi line` (`m`)

      - If you need this behavior (where `^` and `$` match the start and end of *each line* in multi-line strings), prepend `(?m)` to your regex.
    - If you're testing a regex to use with `-match` (which only ever looks for the *first* match), *unselect* the `global` (`g`) option.

      - Note that .NET has no `g` regex option as such; whether or not repeated matching is performed depends on *which API method* you call.
      - In PowerShell, `-match` invariably only looks for *one* match,<sup>[1]</sup> whereas `-replace` invariably looks for *all* (i.e. behaves as if `g` were in effect, as known from languages such as JavaScript and PHP).
  - **Type or paste your regex**:

    - *Without* any enclosing quoting (typically, `'...'`), as the enclosing delimiters are *implied* by the chosen regex flavor, as visualized in the GUI.
    - However, the implied quoting in this case is a *C#* verbatim string literal (`@"..."`), which means:

      - You must **escape any `"` chars. embedded in your regex as `""`**, unlike in PowerShell (where it's best to enclose regexes in `'...'`, in which case embedded `"` require *no* escaping; inside `"..."`, `` `" `` is typically used to escape embedded `"`, which would *not* work in this case; however, `""` works in PowerShell too).
      - If your originally `'...'`-enclosed regex contains PowerShell-escaped embedded `'` chars., i.e. `''`, you must replace them with `'`, otherwise *two* `'` would be matched.
- If you're testing a **[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operation**, click on **`Substitution` under `FUNCTION`**, which makes a `SUBSTITUTION` *input field* appear, in which you can type/paste the replacement expression (the second RHS `-replace` operand, such as `[code]$1[/code]` in this case), again *without* the enclosing quoting.

  - Curiously, escaping appears *not* be necessary in this field, not even of embedded `"` chars. However, the caveat re PowerShell-escaped `'` chars. - `''` - being used verbatim applies here too.
  - Conversely, C# escape sequences such as `\n` to represent actual newlines *are* supported on the site - but they *won't work as such in PowerShell code* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77063036/45375).
  - The result of the substitutions is shown directly below the input field.
- A caveat with respect to the *input (subject) string* (field **`TEST STRING`**) is that **pasting *multi-line* strings invariably inserts converts CRLF (Windows-format) to LF (Unix-format) newlines**. Similarly, it is invariably LF newlines that are created when you *type* a multi-line string.

  - Always using `\r?\n` as part of the regex to match *either* newline form avoids problems resulting from this behavior.
  - However, given that you can only provide a *single* (potentially multi-line) input string, you cannot emulate the typical PowerShell behavior of providing multi-line text as a stream of *multiple, individual (newline-free) lines*, as when you use `Get-Content` (without `-Raw`) and calls to *external programs* as input. To provide a single, multi-line string on the PowerShell, use `Get-Content -Raw` or pipe to [`Out-String`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-String)

[This regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/v1L2C4/1) shows the complete solution based on the guidance above; a screen shot is below:

[image: regex101.com screenshot]

---

<sup>[1] [GitHub issue #7867](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7867) proposes introducing a `-matchall` operator that would look for *all* matches - while the proposal has been green-lighted, no one has stepped up to implement it yet, as of PowerShell 7.2.x</sup>

Comment: great documentation. Very nice

Comment: You stackoverflow fellows are truelly a generous lott. I was wondering how do you turn on Powershells RegEX modifiers allot (Since I could do so easily on RegEx101) so getting RegEx101 to conform to powershell is a brilliant idea. Thanks allot for this brilliant write up.