# Regex works on regex101, but not in powershell... why?

Tags: regex, powershell

I have this test data:

```
^Test data



This is all just test data 


testing 123
ABC>space "ABC"

ABC>
```

And I've setup a regex on regex101.com
`(^\^|ERROR).*((|\n|\r|\w|\W)?)+(?=ABC>)`

The expression is returning just what I want on the site:

[image]

I am using this powershell I wrote to get content similar to the content above and looping through files, and looking for matches of the same regex expression.

```
$files = gci "\\server\path"
$content = @()


ForEach($file in $files){
    # Set script name
    $scriptname = "ABC TEST_081722"

    # Get the name of the task for the logfile's filename. 
    $taskname = "THIS IS A TEST!!!" 

    # Create log file with a datestamp MMDDYY
    $datestamp = (get-date).ToString('MMddyy')
    $logfilepath = "\\server\path\Logs\$($taskname)\$($file.basename).log"
    $log_dir = "\\server\path\Logs\$($taskname)\"

    # Get the content of the log file. We are only interested in getting lines which match a regex for our command line and our output line. 
    $content_raw = get-content $logfilepath -raw

    $content_raw -match "(^\^|ERROR).*((|\n|\r|\w|\W)?)+(?=ABC>)"
    
    Write-host -f yellow $file.fullname
    $matches
    $matches.clear()

                                                                        
    start-sleep -s 2
}
```

The regex finds a match in two of my three test files, but not the first one which has the exact same string content as my example above. Why does it find a match in the 2nd and 3rd file but not the first?

The content of the 2nd and 3rd file are like so

```
ABC>W !,MSG

ERROR^BATCH~Batch in use
ABC>space "ABC"
```

So these two files do not have a line starting with a "^" symbol. It starts with "ERROR" which I accounted for with my OR statement in my regex. I just don't understand how it is able to find the lines which start with "ERROR" find, but not finding the lines from the first file which starts with "^" carat.

Comment: Oh I see.  The first file would work without the blank line one.  It would be nice if that were text instead of a picture.  Select-string is nice in powershell 7 since it highlights the match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following regex instead:

`(?sm)(?:^\^|^ERROR).*?(?=\r?\nABC>)`

<sup>Note: This is a streamlined, working version of your regex (without capture groups); a *corrected* form of *your* regex would be [`(?m)(^\^|^ERROR).*((|\n|\r|\w|\W)?)+(?=ABC>)`](https://regex101.com/r/dc5U66/1), for the reasons explained below.</sup>

Note that PowerShell's operators are case-*insensitive* by default (as is PowerShell in general). For case-sensitivity, use the `c`-prefixed operator variants, i.e., `-cmatch` in this case.

See [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/m1y0TF/2), where you can experiment with text from your files interactively.

---

As for **what you tried**:

- `^` only matches at the start of *individual lines* if the **`MultiLine` regex option** is in effect, which you can activate using inline syntax with **`(?m)`** - note that, **unlike PowerShell, regex101.com has this option turned on *by default*** (see the option letters such as `gm` to the right of the regex input field), which would explain why you didn't see the problem there.

  - Similarly, `(?s)` activates the `SingleLine` regex option, which makes `.` match newline characters (`\n`) too.
- `^\^|ERROR` applies the start-of-input/line `^` metacharacter only to the (escaped) `^` character, not also to `ERROR` on the other side of the alternation (`|`).

  - Your test data wasn't at the very start of your input file (as shown in the screenshot), causing the `^` to be ineffective in the absence of `(?m)`.
  - Conversely, because substring `ERROR` was (accidentally) *not* anchored, it still matched (but would match *anywhere* on a line).

---

Note:

- As of this writing, **[regex101.com](https://regex101.com) has *no* dedicated PowerShell support, and the closest approximation, .NET (C#),  has defaults that are at odds with PowerShell's defaults**.
- For **guidance on how to use regex101.com with PowerShell**, including a link to a feature request to introduce PowerShell support in the future, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111570/45375).

Comment: This is great and very informative answer, thanks for sharing. Just curious if powershell regex engine is not supported in regex101 site, so do we have any other online site for demo OR its only we need to test it as a .ps1 program only to test it, just wanted to know, Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, @RavinderSingh13. PowerShell doesn't have its own regex engine, it uses .NET's, just like C# (or any .NET language). However, (a) PowerShell uses different _defaults_ (`(?i)`, i.e. case-INsensitivity is implied), (b) regex101.com assumes `(?m)` by default, which isn't even the .NET engine's default (_global_ matching is also assumed, and whether that applies depends on which specific .NET method / PowerShell operator you use), and (c) rege101.com assumes that the regex is specified as a _C#_ verbatim string, whose escaping rules differ from single-quoted PowerShell strings.

Comment: This is very informative @mklement0 Thank you for letting know, cheers.

Comment: Glad to hear it, @RavinderSingh13. To summarize: You _can_ already make regex101.com work with PowerShell, but (a) you need to (first select flavor `.NET (C#)` and) adjust the default matching options and (b) if your `'...'`-enclosed PowerShell regex contains `"` or `'`, you need to modify it to satisfy the syntax of a C# verbatim string. Hopefully, the [feature request to introduce specific PowerShell support](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/1838), if implemented, will make that unnecessary. I suggest up-voting it, if you too would like to see it implemented.

Comment: Sure, I will try to up-vote it from mobile, Good to know already things are moving to implement powershell's regex online demo(in regex101 site), cheers.

Comment: This does not explain why it finds the regex if the line starts with "ERROR" but does not if the line starts with carot. I fail to understand how case sensitivity would cause it to fail on a carot.

Comment: I do find this solution is working as far as the expression goes, if you can explain more the pieces that differ from my own regex expression, and what they do I'll mark this as the answer.

Comment: @shadow2020, the case-sensitivity is _incidental_ here: I only mentioned it because this PowerShell default differs from that of the .NET regex engine itself, and that _if_ case matters, you should use `-cmatch`, not `-match`.

Comment: @shadow2020, in the absence of complete information in your question, this answer _guessed_ that the absence of regex option `(?m)` caused your problem, as it would then only match your test string _at the very start of the file_. Does this not apply?

Comment: @shadow2020: Note that regex101.com turns on `(?m)` _by default_ (see the option letters such as `gm` to the right of the regex input field), which explains why it worked there, but not in PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you, I was looking more for what I did wrong with my expression versus yours. I tried adding the (?m) to mine and it's freaking out so I just wanted to make sure I understood where I went wrong. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks for accepting, @shadow2020. The answer explains _one_ problem with your regex: the accidental non-anchoring of `ERROR`. Apart from that, with `(?m)` at the very start of the string, it should work: `(?m)(^\^|^ERROR).*((|\n|\r|\w|\W)?)+(?=ABC>)`, but the reformulation at the top of this answer is simpler. Here's [another regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/dc5U66/1) that shows the corrected form of yours.