# PowerShell - Get everything after the first "-"

Tags: windows, powershell

I have the following code:

```
$TodayDate = Get-Date -Format "dd-MM-yyyy"
$Student = Student01 - Project 01-02 - $TodayDate

Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White "$Student"; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " - was delivered!"
```

This script returns in the console:

```
Student01 - Project 01-02 - dd-MM-yyyy - was delivered
```

How is it possible to return only everything after the first "-"?, that is `Project 01-02 - dd-MM-yyyy - was delivered`?

I thought about using .split, but I couldn't make it work so that it returns everything after the first "-".

Comment: You could use `-Split` to split it in 2, then grab the 2nd string after `-`. `-Replace` could also work here. Can you update your post with your attempts at this?

Comment: I couldn't get it to work with `-split`, but I used `.Replace` and it worked, the final script looked like this: `Write-Host -NoNewline -ForegroundColor White "$(($Student).Replace("Student01 -", "$null"))"; Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green " - was delivered!"`

Comment: $student = "Student01 - Project 01-02 - dd-MM-yyyy - was delivered"  $index = $student.IndexOf("-") $student = $student.Substring($index + 1).Trim()  Write-Host $student

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem boils down to wanting to **remove a *prefix* from a string**.

Given that the prefix to remove cannot be defined as a static, literal string, but is defined by the (included) ***first* occurrence of a *separator***, you have two PowerShell-idiomatic **options**:

- Use the **[`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split)** operator, which **allows you to limit the number of resulting tokens**; if you limit them to *2*, everything after the first separator is returned as-is; thus, the 2nd (and last) token (accessible by index `[-1]`) then contains the suffix of interest:

  ```bash
  $str = 'Student01 - Project 01-02 - dd-MM-yyyy - was delivered'

  # Split by ' - ', and return at most 2 tokens, then extract the 2nd (last) token.
  # -> 'Project 01-02 - dd-MM-yyyy - was delivered'
  ($str -split ' - ', 2)[-1]
  ```
- Use the **[`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator)** operator, which (like `-split` by default) is [regex](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Regular_Expressions)-based, and **allows you to formulate a *pattern* that matches any prefix up to and including the first separator**, which can then be removed:

  ```bash
  $str = 'Student01 - Project 01-02 - dd-MM-yyyy - was delivered'

  # Match everything up to the *first* ' - ', and remove it.
  # Note that not specifying a *replacement string* (second RHS operator)
  # implicitly uses '' and therefore *removes* what was matched.
  # -> 'Project 01-02 - dd-MM-yyyy - was delivered'
  $str -replace '^.+? - '
  ```

  - For an explanation of the regex (`^.+? -` ) and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/RvTsGy/1).

Comment: Your explanation could not have been better!

I'm a beginner, especially in the PowerShell language, so I always like to understand the reason for things, that way I can evolve.

I didn't know about the application of the regex `(^.+? - )`, I found it very interesting, it makes the job a lot easier and increases the possibilities.

I also really liked the website you indicated, I didn't know it, I'll probably use it a lot.

Thank you very much for your attention and patience!

Comment: I'm glad to hear it helped, and thanks for the nice feedback, @TyroneHirt. Yes. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) is a great site, both for studying and troubleshooting regular expressions (regexes). Note that you'll have to tweak the defaults to make it work like PowerShell, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111570/45375).