# regular expression matches more than it should in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell

Hi I have a script that tries to replace one a block of
`<p></p>` 
with text image002.jpg or png. but it always replace more that it should. Could someone help to improve the regex. I did ask ChatGPT but no luck:=). The one who got the answer must smarter than AI.

```
# Assign the input text to a variable using single quotes
$content = 
@'
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 1</p>

<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white"><span style="font-family:"Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
color:black"><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_2" o:spid="_x0000_i1028"
 type="#_x0000_t75" alt="" style="width:75pt;height:75pt">
 <v:imagedata src="test_files/image002.png" o:href="cid:98eba38d-7414-46ec-a87a-8eca235a6e5c"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img border=0 width=100 height=100
src="test_files/image002.png" style="height:1.041in;width:1.041in" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_2"><![endif]></span><span
style="color:black"><o:p></o:p></span></p>

<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 2</p>
'@

$pattern = "(?s)<p\b[^>]*>.*?\bimage002\.(png|jpg)\b.*?</p>"
#"<p[^>]*>(.*?)(image002\.(png|jpg))(.*?)<\/p>"
$replacement = "<p>replaced</p>"

[regex]::Replace($content, $pattern, $replacement, [System.Text.RegularExpressions.RegexOptions]::Singleline)
# Use -replace operator to find and replace all matches
$content = $content -replace $pattern,$replacement
# Write the modified content to the console or a file
Write-Host $content
```

The `<p>` elements I want to keep as-is contain `to be kept` above.

With my current approach, the first `<p>` element is also being replaced, which I don't want.

Comment: ***;-}***   **ChatGPT, is just pulling for many places, and as of now, it's more often wrong than many would believe/accept, especially for tech(code)-related stuff.** ***;-}*** Then your regex is not valid. Place your target text in a sight like RegEx101, and then you RegEx in the input box and make needed changes to hit your use case. RegEx101 will highlight all your errors in real time as you type them in. If you are trying to replace stuff between those HTML tags, then yes it's going to grab them all. If you are after one set, then you have to tell it that. Show you the expected results.

Comment: ChatGPT is great for creating a starting code filled with errors, but also filled with technics you might not have thought of.  If done correctly, it can save time writing and discovering commands you didn't know people were using to get a job done, but in the end you nearly always will have a notable amount of editing and research to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to ensure that there's no *additional* `<p>` between the one you want to match and the subsequent `image002.png` and `image002.jpg` matches.
- You can use the following subexpression that involves a negative lookahead assertion to ensure that: `(?:.(?!<p\b[^>]*>))+`

```bash
# Note: (?:…) is a *non*-capturing group.
#       (?!…) is a negative lookahead assertion.
$pattern = '(?s)<p\b[^>]*>(?:.(?!<p\b[^>]*>))+\bimage002\.(?:png|jpg)\b.*?</p>'
$replacement = '<p>replaced</p>'
$content -replace $pattern, $replacement

$content # Output the result
```

For an explanation of the regex and the ability to experiment with it, see [this regex101.com page](https://regex101.com/r/Qbp6wO/6).

Output:

```bash
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 1</p>

<p>replaced</p>

<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 2</p>
```

Comment: Even though Regex101 doesn't like your $pattern, it works LOL. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, @Cliff, but note that it does like it - you just need to switch to ".NET (C#)" as the language, just like the [link already included in the answer](https://regex101.com/r/Qbp6wO/6) does.

Comment: @Chris, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73111570/45375) for guidance on using regex101.com with PowerShell, specifically.

Comment: Ahhaaa, I thought regex is a universal syntax expression, apparently, it's not. Thanks again.

Comment: My pleasure, @Chris. There are two aspects that make regexes non-universal: (a) there are regex "dialects": different engines support different features / can behave differently, so the choice of engine may matter and (b) how regex _literals_ are expressed differs by what programming language you call from. For instance, PHP and JavaScript use `/.../`, whereas PowerShell and C# have _no_ regex literals and use _string_ literals to specify regexes. As a result, the escaping requirements differ. E.g, in PHP and JavaScript you need to escape `/`, whereas in a PowerShell string you don't.

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment.

Let's say you are after all text in between the HTML paragraph tags, then it's just something like this:

```
(?<=>).*(?=<\/p>)
```

So, if you'd use the above pattern on your posted text, you'd get this as a result:

```
Clear-Host
[RegEX]::Matches('<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 1</p>
    
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white"><span style="font-family:"Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
color:black"><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_2" o:spid="_x0000_i1028"
    type="#_x0000_t75" alt="" style="width:75pt;height:75pt">
    <v:imagedata src="test_files/image002.png" o:href="cid:98eba38d-7414-46ec-a87a-8eca235a6e5c"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img border=0 width=100 height=100
src="test_files/image002.png" style="height:1.041in;width:1.041in" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_2"><![endif]></span><span
style="color:black"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 2</p>
', '(?<=>).*(?=<\/p>)').Value
# Results
<#
to be kept 1
<o:p></o:p></span>
    
to be kept 2
#>
```

Of course, there is more clean-up you'd need to consider, based on what you are really after, of which you have not yet shown us the before and after goals

If you are looking at just the stuff this jpg|png only string, where only the name should be replaced, not the extension:

```
"test_files/image002.png"
```

Then the same approach could apply. For example:

```
(?<=src="test_files.).*(?=\(.jpg|.png)
```

So...

```
Clear-Host
[RegEX]::Matches('<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 1</p>
    
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white"><span style="font-family:"Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
color:black"><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_2" o:spid="_x0000_i1028"
    type="#_x0000_t75" alt="" style="width:75pt;height:75pt">
    <v:imagedata src="test_files/image002.png" o:href="cid:98eba38d-7414-46ec-a87a-8eca235a6e5c"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img border=0 width=100 height=100
src="test_files/image002.png" style="height:1.041in;width:1.041in" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_2"><![endif]></span><span
style="color:black"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 2</p>
', '(?<=src="test_files.).*(?=\(.jpg|.png)').Value
# Results
<#
image002
image002
#>
```

Of course, then the replacement is a straightforward thing at this point.

```
Clear-Host
[regex]::replace('
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 1</p>
    
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white"><span style="font-family:"Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
color:black"><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_2" o:spid="_x0000_i1028"
    type="#_x0000_t75" alt="" style="width:75pt;height:75pt">
    <v:imagedata src="test_files/image002.png" o:href="cid:98eba38d-7414-46ec-a87a-8eca235a6e5c"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img border=0 width=100 height=100
src="test_files/image002.png" style="height:1.041in;width:1.041in" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_2"><![endif]></span><span
style="color:black"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 2</p>
', 
'(?<=src="test_files.).*(?=\(.jpg|.png)', 'ReplacemenImage')
# Results
<#
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 1</p>
    
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white"><span style="font-family:"Source Sans Pro",sans-serif;
color:black"><!--[if gte vml 1]><v:shape id="Picture_x0020_2" o:spid="_x0000_i1028"
    type="#_x0000_t75" alt="" style="width:75pt;height:75pt">
    <v:imagedata src="test_files/ReplacemenImage.png" o:href="cid:98eba38d-7414-46ec-a87a-8eca235a6e5c"/>
</v:shape><![endif]--><![if !vml]><img border=0 width=100 height=100
src="test_files/ReplacemenImage.png" style="height:1.041in;width:1.041in" v:shapes="Picture_x0020_2"><![endif]></span><span
style="color:black"><o:p></o:p></span></p>
    
<p class=xmsonormal style="background:white">to be kept 2</p>
```

Comment: thank you for your time. As said I will need to replace the whole block <p </p> which contains the image002.jpg|png.