# RegEx to selectively insert newlines (line breaks) works on regex101.com, but not in PowerShell

Tags: regex, powershell, replace, newline

I have some text imported as a single string via, `$String = Get-Content -Path 'c:\temp\mytext.txt' -Raw`:

```
Lorem ipsum et cras praesent mollis ullamcorper laoreet mauris imperdiet quisque
- red
- green
- blue
Lorem ipsum et cras praesent mollis ullamcorper laoreet mauris imperdiet quisque
ac adipiscing mauris ante class placerat per sem quisque phasellus sociosqu, mollis
- red
- green
- blue
bluorem ipsum et cras praesent mollis ullamcorper laoreet mauris imperdiet quisque
```

I want to add a new line before the first line starting with `-` (Lines with `"- red"`) and after the last line starting with `-` (Lines with `"- blue"`), the output should look like:

```
Lorem ipsum et cras praesent mollis ullamcorper laoreet mauris imperdiet quisque

- red
- green
- blue

Lorem ipsum et cras praesent mollis ullamcorper laoreet mauris imperdiet quisque
ac adipiscing mauris ante class placerat per sem quisque phasellus sociosqu, mollis

- red
- green
- blue

bluorem ipsum et cras praesent mollis ullamcorper laoreet mauris imperdiet quisque
```

For the first lines starting with `-`, according to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/2cPh0y/1), this RegEx looks to be it, `\n-\s.*(\n)[^-]`, but when I attempt to apply it with PowerShell, `$String -replace '\n-\s.*(\n)[^-]', '\n$1'`, the line itself gets truncated, even though the capture group `$1` is consists of a single token, `\n`.

Also for the last lines starting with `-`, according to [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/0W9jOk/1), this RegEx looks to be it, `\n-\s.*(\n)[^-]`, but in PowerShell, `$String -replace '\n-\s.*(\n)[^-]', '$1\n'` gives me:

```
Lorem ipsum et cras praesent mollis ullamcorper laoreet mauris imperdiet quisque
ac adipiscing mauris ante class placerat per sem quisque phasellus sociosqu, mollis
- red
\ngreen
...
```

My RegEx is weak, I tried my best to conform the regex101.com settings to PowerShell's, but something is just out of line here.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr**:

Replace:

> `'$1\n'`

with: `` "`$1`n" ``, or - for conceptual clarity - with `` ('$1' + "`n") ``<sup>[1]</sup>

For an optimized solution using a *single* `-replace` operation, see [Doug Maurer's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77063921/45375).

---

###### Background information:

- [regex101.com](https://regex101.com) is a great resource, but its .NET support is C#-focused, which doesn't map cleanly onto PowerShell.

  - See [GitHub issue #1838](https://github.com/firasdib/Regex101/issues/1838) for a suggestion to make the site more PowerShell-friendly.
- In PowerShell [string literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Quoting_Rules), `\` has *no* special meaning, so including `\n` in the substitution operand of the [`-replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Comparison_Operators#replacement-operator) operator causes `\n` to be included *verbatim*.

  - To produce a *literal* LF character via an *escape sequence* in PowerShell requires use of an expandable (interpolating) PowerShell string (`"..."`) and escape sequence `` `n ``, using `` ` `` PowerShell's [escape character](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Special_Characters) `` ` ``, the so-called *backtick*.
- In your case, `$1` is a placeholder to be passed *to .NET's regex engine*, and given that `$1` also looks like a *PowerShell variable reference*, inside `"..."` you must *escape the `$` char.* to prevent *expansion* (up-front string interpolation based on variables by PowerShell), hence the use of `` `$ `` above.

  - Note that `-replace` uses [`System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace) behind the scenes, and its substitution (replacement) operand maps onto the `replacement` parameter, which is *not* a regex, and itself doesn't understand `\`-based escape sequences - all it knows are [`$`-prefixed tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/substitutions-in-regular-expressions), referring to elements of what the regex matched (such as `$1` to refer to the what the first capture group captured).
  - From C#, using a `"..."` string (rather than a verbatim `@"..."` string), something like `"$1\n"` would cause *C#* to expand the `\n` escape sequence *up front* (to a literal LF char.; it would leave the `$` alone, as this char. has no special meaning in C# strings), and is this behavior that regex101.com assumes when you use its `.NET (C#)` flavor.
- `` ('$1' + "`n") `` is a conceptually clearer alternative to `` "`$1`n" ``, because it separates the *verbatim* part (`'...'`) from the *interpolated* one (`"..."`), making it clear which parts are provided by up-front string interpolation vs. which parts are interpreted by the .NET regex engine. See footnote [1] for a potential pitfall.

---

<sup>[1] In general, if there's a chance that the `"..."` part starts with a *digit*, use `${1}` instead of `$1` for disambiguation, e.g. `('${1}' + "7 $up")`</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to handle both conditions at once. [mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0)'s answer offers great clarity into the nuts and bolts. Basically this solution matches from a dash until a new line that is not followed with a dash directly after it.

```
$string -replace '(?s)-.+?(?=\n[^-]+)',('{0}$0{0}' -f "`n")
```